# Using SUM throws "values aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning..." error

Tags: postgresql

I try to use SUM with json_array_elements_text in a PostgreSql query as shown on the **[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=327d538fb22754dc0b08833074cead86)**.

```
SELECT
    details->>'city' as city,
    SUM(json_array_elements_text(details->'prices')::numeric) as total_prices
FROM my_table
group by city
```

However, encounter the following error:

> *aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls LINE :SUM(json_array_elements_text(details->'prices')::numeric...*

So, how to fix the problem?

Here is the records:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(details) VALUES('
    {
        "city": "London",
        "name": "Sainburry",
        "quantities": [112, 145, 222, 122, 124],
        "prices": [4, 4, 4, 2, 3],
        "dates": ["13.05.2020", "14.05.2020", "15.05.2020", "16.05.2020", "17.05.2020"]
    }',
    '{
        "city": "London",
        "name": "Forever",
        "quantities": [33, 44, 432, 134, 57],
        "prices": [5, 4, 7, 8, 3],
        "dates": ["13.05.2020", "14.05.2020", "15.05.2020", "16.05.2020", "17.05.2020"]
    }',
    '{
        "city": "Edinburgh",
        "name": "Circle",
        "quantities": [22, 44, 234, 123, 66],
        "prices": [5, 2, 8, 4, 6],
        "dates": ["13.05.2020", "14.05.2020", "15.05.2020", "16.05.2020", "17.05.2020"]
    }
    ');
```

Comment: Please post the query in the question itself, not just a link to it. What do you want to achieve with the query? How do you want multiple array elements to be handled?

Comment: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for help. Should I follow the method on **Baroque queries** of that page? Any post pls according to my question?

Comment: @Bergi Have you look at query?

Comment: Normalize your model and the query gets super easy

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I am newbie in postgresql, could you post it and make explanations on the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the set-returning function into a [lateral query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
SELECT
    details->>'city' as city,
    SUM(price::numeric) as total_prices
FROM my_table,
    LATERAL json_array_elements_text(details->'prices') AS prices(price)
GROUP BY city
```

<sup>([updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d11fd290c244f3b52d367d24f422efaf))</sup>

Comment: I encountered *"ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "prices" LINE 5:     LATERAL json_array_elements_text(details->'prices'::nume..."* error. I also changed cast just after `prices` but nothing has changed.

Comment: And what is **AS prices(price)**? I have never seen such a kind of alias :(

Comment: @Jason oops, I forgot to keep the type cast in the select expression. Fixed now, with working demo.

Comment: @Jason That's an [alias for table functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS), which allows you naming not only the table but also its columns

Comment: Yes, this time is ok and I also found when I try. In that case, Cannot we cast in this method like `json_array_elements_text((details->'prices')::numeric)` as in `SUM()`?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the difference between `AS prices(price)` and `AS prices`?

Comment: I guess you could make something like `LATERAL (SELECT json_array_elements_text(details->'prices')::numeric) AS …` or `LATERAL (SELECT 1::numeric FROM json_array_elements_text(details->'prices')) AS …`

Comment: @Jason If I understood the documentation correctly, `AS prices` is a shorthand for `AS prices(prices)`, where effectively the column has the same alias as the whole table (which doesn't make much of a difference for a single-column table)

Comment: I forced to use **LATERAL (SELECT json_array_elements_text(details->'prices')::numeric) AS…** but not managed. It is vers strange that PostgreSql makes casting as a puzzle :( It would be better to cast the source instead of the other places wherever we use it.

Comment: @Jason [It does work for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7ae118f0a72d0d2a13ff7c390cf8e8d4)

Comment: Yes, it works many thanks. But providing that using **alias for table functions**, otherwise not work. In this case sometimes it may be needed ;)